# How to represent and manage polygons in the polar region that cross from East Russia to North America?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, clip, sf

I'm trying to create a map of the Eastern part of Russia and the northern part of North America and I need to clip the coastline around that area. However, when I am trying to cut the section using sf the algorithm is not cutting the lines properly. Also, when I try to plot the polygon that I am using to clip the area I got the "opposite" of what I'm hoping to get. So, if I run this:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Get coastline data a example

dt <- rnaturalearth::ne_coastline(scale="large")

clip_boundary <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(cbind(c(160,160,-80, -80,160),
                                              c(55 , 90 ,90,  55,55)))),
                          crs = 4326)

arctic <- st_crop(dt, clip_boundary)
ggplot(dt) + geom_sf() + geom_sf(data=clip_boundary, alpha=0.8) +
  geom_sf(data=arctic, alpha=0.5, col="red", size=3) + theme_bw() +
  lims(y=c(50, 90))
```

I get
[image]
The purple dashed line indicates what I was hoping to get (added manually to the figure). Notice that the cropping seems to be using that area, even when the figure shows the "complement" of that area.
Further, the blue arrows show sections of the coastline not kept in the result.

so, I tried adding intermediate points to tell the computer that I want to draw the plot in a particular way,

```
clip_boundary <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(cbind(c(160,160,180,-160,-80, -80,-160,160),
                                              c( 55, 90, 90,  90, 90,  55,  55,55)))),
                        crs = 4326)

arctic <- st_crop(dt, clip_boundary)
ggplot(dt) + geom_sf() + geom_sf(data=clip_boundary, alpha=0.8) +
  geom_sf(data=arctic, alpha=0.5, col="red", size=3) + theme_bw() +
  lims(y=c(50, 90))
```

but then, neither worked: the region is pretty much the same (except for a couple of lines on top) and the clipping was terrible.
How could I address this problem? Is there an efficient way to indicate that I want to draw the area to clip in a particular direction? Or should I create two polygons (one from 160-180 and another from -180 to -80)? If the latter, is there a function that can automatically do that?

[image]